# Computing the Sum of Log n Bits in First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, descriptive-complexity

I have read the so-called Bit-Sum Lemma from

Neil Immerman. "Descriptive Complexity" (Lemma 1.18) and from

Barrington, Immerman and Straubing. "On uniformity within $NC^1$" (Lemma 7.2)

but I am unable to understand a small part of the proof.

The statement of the Bit-Sum Lemma goes as follows:

Let $BSUM(x,y)$ hold iff $y$ is equal to the sum of bits in $x$'s binary representation. Then $BSUM$ is first-order expressible using a total order on the universe and the BIT predicate (Remember that $BIT(x,y)$ holds if the $y$-th bit of $x$ is $1$).

A rough sketch of the proof that is given in both of the above sources, goes as follows: assuming that $\log n \geq (\log \log n)^2$ (the finitely many cases for which this is not true can be handled by a first order formula). We think that the binary representation of every element in the universe is divided in $\log \log n$ many parts each of them having length $\log \log n$ bits. We guess (i.e. we existentially quantify over) some $z$, such that part $i$ of $z$ contains the sum of the bits of $x$ until and including part $i$. In order to assert that the choice of $z$ is correct we guess another element of the universe $w$, such that part $i$ of $w$ contains exactly the sum of the bits of part $i$ of $x$. Finally using carry look-ahead addition we verify that our choice of $z$ is correct: that is part $i$ or $z$ is equal to the sum of part $i-1$ of $z$ plus part $i$ of $w$. Finally $y$ is equal to the final part of $z$.

The only thing I am missing in the above proof is how can we assert that part $i$ of $z$ is equal to the sum of all bits in part $i$ of $x$. In the above sources they treat this verification as being trivial. However if this verification trivial, why it is not trivial to verify that $y$ is equal to the bit sum of $x$ from the very beginning? The answer should probably depend on the fact that the length of $x$ is $\log n$ bits, whereas the length of part $i$ is only $\log \log n$ bits. I am unable to see why this restriction in length makes computing the bit sum easier. Any help would be appreciated.